# Cross-validation with speedglm for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, cross-validation, speedglm

I would like to run a cross-validation function like `cv.glm` on a logistic regression model built with `speedglm` on a large (millions of rows) data set.  Does any such function exist?

I am finding that `cv.glm` (from `boot` package) and the `train` function from `caret` do not recognize `speedglm` models.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could build your own caret model. Or ask on github to add speedglm to the caret library.

Comment: Why do you need to cross-validate with that much data? Set aside 250K and use that to validate your model. Unless you have a really low event rate, that should suffice

Comment: Thanks, I will try to follow both of your suggestions.

Comment: You can try the `sperrorest` package. It provides a generic CV interface. All you need is a working `predict()` function.